# passport.js doesn't populate data on login/signup

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

Versions:

- "passport": "0.4.1",
- "passport-local": "1.0.0",
- "passport-local-mongoose": "6.0.1"
- "express": "4.17.1",
- "express-session": "1.17.1",

My session middleware

```
let sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true
    }
});
```

For serializeUser/deserializeUser I'm using my custom callbacks:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    db.User.findById(user._id)
        .populate('role', ['code'])
        .exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) { 
                console.info('\n Error:', err);
            } else {
                console.info(11, data);
                done(null, data);
            }
        })
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    db.User.findById(user._id)
        .populate('role', ['code'])
        .exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) { 
                console.info('\n Error:', err);
            } else {
                done(null, data);
            }
        })
});
```

it works on any request, and I get user role just fine.
But it doesn't work on login:

```
// User object from passport.authenticate callback
{
  _id: 5eb8596e049f2131487725eb,
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  login: 'test',
  role: 5eb855dc91fd0548fc968939,
  salt: /* MY SALT */,
  hash: /* MY PASSWORD HASH */,
  createdAt: 2020-05-10T19:43:42.797Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-05-10T19:43:42.797Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

But serializeUser does work and it's called after auth, returning User object with correct role object:

```
// user object on serialize-deserialize User, i.e. on any request other than login/signup
{
  _id: 5eb8596e049f2131487725eb,
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  login: 'test',
  role: { _id: 5eb855dc91fd0548fc968939, code: 'tech_sup' },
  createdAt: 2020-05-10T19:43:42.797Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-05-10T19:43:42.797Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Problem is, it's populating after passport.authenticate therefore it's not updating req.user.

How to make passport populate data with mongoose on login/signup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if someone is struggling from the same problem:

I'm also using `passport-local-mongoose`, I guess for any other store you need something equal:

1) Be sure your passport.**serializeUser** **AND** passport.**deserializeUser**  accept default handler (in my case it's db.User.serializeUser() and db.User.deserializeUser() respectively)
2) In place where you use passport-local-mongoose for your User schema add next option - findByUserName:

```
User.plugin(passportMongoose, {
    /** any other options you use for passport-local-mongoose plugin */
    [...pluginOptions]
    /** added option to solve the problem */
    findByUsername: (model, queryParameters) => model.findOne(queryParameters).populate('role', ['code']),
});
```